# how to combine bash cycle for with different variables

Tags: bash, scripting, router, cycle, iptables

I have two networks:

```
FORWARDS="10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16"
```

In cycle I'm allowing tcp udp icmp from same network to same

```
for ipo in $FORWARDS;do
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s $ipo -d $ipo -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s $ipo -d $ipo -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -s $ipo -d $ipo -j ACCEPT
done
```

But I need to allow same networks from one to eachother, howto add iptables rules below in cycle to reduce number of lines:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/8 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s 10.0.0.0/8 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -s 10.0.0.0/8 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops:

```
for ipo1 in $FORWARDS; do
    for ip2 in $FORWARD; do
        iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s $ipo1 -d $ipo2 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s $ipo1 -d $ipo2 -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -s $ipo1 -d $ipo2 -j ACCEPT
    done
done
```

Comment: and allow forward from $ipo1 to $ipo1? I ment in one cycle... if any how it's possible...

Comment: It will get those whenever `$ipo1` and `$ipo2` are the same.

Comment: sorry it's ok, my mistake and yours in second line ip2 variable